# how avoid BAD_ACCESS with UINavigationControllerDelegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, delegates

I've got 3 viewController A,B,C.
From A i have a push segue to B and from B a push segue to C. There is no problem going forward and without set  controller C as UINavigationControllerDelegate i can also going backward from C->B and from B->A. If in viewDidLoad of C i set:

```
 self.navigationController.delegate = self;
```

because i need the method navigationController:willShowViewController
I can still going from A->B->C and from C->B calling the method that i need but if i press the back button from B->A my app crash saying BAD_ACCESS.How can i avoid this?Thanks in advance

```
libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend:
0x14e00a4:  movl   8(%esp), %ecx
0x14e00a8:  movl   4(%esp), %eax
0x14e00ac:  testl  %eax, %eax
0x14e00ae:  je     0x14e0110                 ; objc_msgSend + 108
0x14e00b0:  movl   (%eax), %edx
0x14e00b2:  movzwl 12(%edx), %eax                                 Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address0x408e3b7c)
0x14e00b6:  andl   %ecx, %eax
0x14e00b8:  shll   $3, %eax
0x14e00bb:  addl   8(%edx), %eax
0x14e00be:  cmpl   (%eax), %ecx
0x14e00c0:  jne    0x14e00c5                 ; objc_msgSend + 33
0x14e00c2:  jmpl   *4(%eax)
0x14e00c5:  cmpl   $0, (%eax)
0x14e00c8:  je     0x14e0119                 ; objc_msgSend + 117
0x14e00ca:  cmpl   8(%edx), %eax
0x14e00cd:  je     0x14e00d9                 ; objc_msgSend + 53
0x14e00cf:  subl   $8, %eax
0x14e00d2:  cmpl   (%eax), %ecx
0x14e00d4:  jne    0x14e00c5                 ; objc_msgSend + 33
0x14e00d6:  jmpl   *4(%eax)
0x14e00d9:  movzwl 12(%edx), %eax
0x14e00dd:  shll   $3, %eax
0x14e00e0:  addl   8(%edx), %eax
0x14e00e3:  jmp    0x14e00f2                 ; objc_msgSend + 78
0x14e00e5:  cmpl   $0, (%eax)
0x14e00e8:  je     0x14e0119                 ; objc_msgSend + 117
0x14e00ea:  cmpl   8(%edx), %eax
0x14e00ed:  je     0x14e00f9                 ; objc_msgSend + 85
0x14e00ef:  subl   $8, %eax
0x14e00f2:  cmpl   (%eax), %ecx
0x14e00f4:  jne    0x14e00e5                 ; objc_msgSend + 65
0x14e00f6:  jmpl   *4(%eax)
0x14e00f9:  pushl  %ebp
0x14e00fa:  movl   %esp, %ebp
0x14e00fc:  pushl  $0
0x14e00fe:  pushl  $0
0x14e0100:  pushl  $0
0x14e0102:  pushl  %edx
0x14e0103:  pushl  %ecx
0x14e0104:  movl   8(%ebp), %ecx
0x14e0107:  pushl  %ecx
0x14e0108:  calll  0x14ce720                 ; objc_msgSend_corrupt_cache_error
0x14e010d:  nopl   (%eax)
0x14e0110:  xorl   %edx, %edx
0x14e0112:  xorps  %xmm0, %xmm0
0x14e0115:  xorps  %xmm1, %xmm1
0x14e0118:  ret    
0x14e0119:  movl   8(%esp), %ecx
0x14e011d:  movl   4(%esp), %eax
0x14e0121:  pushl  %ebp
0x14e0122:  movl   %esp, %ebp
0x14e0124:  subl   $12, %esp
0x14e0127:  pushl  %edx
0x14e0128:  pushl  %ecx
0x14e0129:  pushl  %eax
0x14e012a:  calll  0x14d8017                 ; _class_lookupMethodAndLoadCache3
0x14e012f:  leave  
0x14e0130:  cmpl   %eax, %eax
0x14e0132:  jmpl   *%eax
```

Comment: What is the stack trace?

Comment: Where can i see it? @coneybeare

Comment: When the code crashes, and Xcode lets you know, you can see it on the debug panel

Comment: What you want from the Xcode console is the error message and backtrace (get the backtrace with the `bt` debugger command. You have provided the assembly code, that is not what we need.

Answer (score 0):

`UINavigationController`'s [`delegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/delegate) property does not retain the value, so if you are using ARC for memory management(the default), C is probably getting deallocated, resulting in the delegate being garbage (which is the usual cause of BAD_ACCESS errors these days). The solution is to simply have some strong reference to C be kept around somewhere.

Comment: what if in navigationController:willShowViewController i put something like self.navigationController.delegate = nil; ?is there some side effect for memory management? @mprudhom

Comment: if i set the delegate to Nil before returning from C to B everything works fine. Why?is it a good practise?

Comment: That should work. If the property were "weak", it would automatically be nilled, but since it is "assign", it can wind up pointing to a released section of memory. So you can manually nil it out whenever you want.